# Need Discord Bot to check if large text block contains key from json

Tags: python, json, dictionary, discord, discord.py

I am making a bot which checks if a message contains a key with a value of "weak", if it does, it should send the keys that are in the message.

However, my code faces two issues.

when i do !grading aban, it gives me a response, however, if i do !grading abi ayyash, (which has spaces) it no longer works,

and also, my code should check if the SPECIFIC key is in the message, if I had a key of "aban test", but I also had a key called "aban" and "test", it shouldnt show me "aban" and "test" seperately as found, but only "aban test"

here is the code.

```
@commands.command()
async def grading(self, ctx, *message):
    found_keys = [weak for weak in message if weak in narrators.keys()]
    nars = ', '.join(found_keys)
    await ctx.send("This is unreliable because of:\n" + nars)
```

heres the json

```
{"aban": "weak", "aban b. abi ayyash": "weak", "abi ayyash": "weak"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by your loop and the `*` in your argument list.

```py
async def command(ctx, *, message):
```

In this (your) case, `!command a string with spaces` will result in `message` being `"a string with spaces"`, which is what you want (judging from your question).

However, as you're looping over the message (`[weak for weak in message]`), you're looping over **every single character** of the string, so `("a", " ", "s", "t", ...)` and none of those are in your dictionary.

I believe you want to check it the *other way around*: check if the keys from the *dictionary* are in the *message*.

Another option is to check separate *words* in the message (instead of characters) & loop over *that*, by changing your parameters to `*message` instead of `*, message` (note the place where the `*` is). This will split your message into a tuple of separate words.

This way, however, you can no longer check for keys of multiple words. That means you'll have to make your loop a bit more complicated. Keep track of a string of previously-seen keys. In every iteration see if `{previous} {current}` is in your dict. If it is, keep going (potentially a longer one of more words is present). If it isn't, then the previous one is the longest possible match & you should add it to the list of "weak words".

This *slightly* more complicated (**it's like 4 lines of basic Python, it's not that hard**) loop is to account for your second issue, where you wanted the longest possible key.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are combinations, and there is a function in itertools called `combinations` that can be used.

We also need to use all the lengths, from 1 to the `len(message) + 1`, so that we exhaust all possibilities. We use the unpacking operator `*` so that we can chain it afterwards.

Also you don't need to use the .keys() method if you are using the `in` operator, as it will automatically check the keys.

```py
from itertools import combinations, chain


@commands.command()
async def grading(self, ctx, *message):
    found_keys = [weak for weak in chain(message, *(combinations(message, i) for i in range(1, len(message)+1))) if (weak_key := " ".join(weak)) in narrators]
    nars = ', '.join(found_keys)
    await ctx.send("This is unreliable because of:\n" + nars)
```

Just for context, this is equivalent to below (just in case it wasn't clear).

```py
from itertools import combinations, chain


@commands.command()
async def grading(self, ctx, *message):
    found_keys = []
    for key_group in chain(message, *(combinations(message, i) for i in range(1, len(message)+1))):
        weak = " ".join(key_group)
        if weak in narrators:
            found_keys.append(weak)
    nars = ', '.join(found_keys)
    await ctx.send("This is unreliable because of:\n" + nars)
```

if you would like to have unordered pairing as well, use `permutations` rather than `combinations`. Look at the [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) on the documentation page for more context